# How do I invoke a postman-defined request within a postman pre-request script?

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

All examples I've seen of calling a REST API within a Pre-Request script use the http API pm.sendRequest().

I'd much rather 'submit' a request that is defined through the Postman UI.  Then, the request details can easily be managed through the Postman UI and shared across multiple Pre-Request scripts.

Is there a Postman API to send/invoke a specific request item in a collection?

Comment: The challenge is that sendRequest() is asynchronous and based on a raw HTTP request, not a Postman-defined request.  And although setNextRequest() supports a Postman request identifier, it occurs after the execution of the script.  

I was hoping there is a synchronous way to send a request based on the request identifier within a script.